# jQuery.fadeIn()/fadeOut(). Not working in IE7+8

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, internet-explorer

I'm have a Ruby on Rails project which displays illustrations. There are category links at the top which fade out the illustrations, replaces it with new content and then fades back in.

I am using jQuery 1.6.2.

It works as expected in Safari 5, Firefox 6, Chrome 14 and IE9. In IE7+8 the html is replaced with the new content but no fade occurs.

To begin with I was using html5 elements so thought it could be that, but I've since replaced them all with divs and the problem still shows. I've tried adding/removing Modernizr and Selectivizr libraries to no effect. Any help is appreciated, code is as follows:

**app/views/illustrations/index.html.erb**

```
<div id="illustrations" class="illustration-list">
  <%= render @illustrations %>
</div>
```

**app/views/illustrations/_illustration.html.erb**

```
<div class="illustration">
  <div class="figure">
    <%= link_to image_tag(illustration.image.url(:thumb), alt: illustration.title), illustration %>
    <div class="figcaption">
      <%= link_to illustration.title, illustration %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**app/views/shared/_category_links.html.erb** - Which triggers the ajax

```
<ul>
  <% category_links.each do |category| -%>
    <li class="<%= category.name.downcase %>">
      <%= link_to category.name, category, remote: true %>
    </li>
  <% end -%>
</ul>
```

and lastly **/app/views/categories/show.js.erb**

```
var data = "<%= escape_javascript(render(@illustrations)) %>";
var div = $('#illustrations');
div.fadeOut("slow", function() {
  div.html(data);
  div.fadeIn('slow');
});
```

**EDIT** Here is an example without the images, but you should be able to get the idea, http://jsbin.com/ifisuh/4/edit#preview.

Comment: Opacity in IE requires DirectX. Are you testing on a VM?

Comment: Put an alert saying: this website will work only on a web browser :P

Comment: @katspaugh I never knew about that, I am on a VM. I'll check it on a Windows machine.

Comment: @NicolaeSurdu It may come to this...

Comment: @katspaugh I've tried a Windows machine and the problem is still there.

Comment: @Jamie, check for duplicate element IDs maybe (`#illustrations`). Check that `data` is properly escaped (unlikely it isn't though, since it gets inserted after all).

Comment: Thanks @katspaugh for helping, but I checked with Firefox's We Developer Toolbar for the Generated Source and there were no duplicate IDs and as far as I can tell, the `data` is fully escaped.

Comment: If you setup a jsbin.com with the generated source, we could help further.

Comment: This is the generated source after clicking a category-link: http://jsbin.com/ecocih/edit#javascript,html. Thanks again @katspaugh

Comment: @Jamie, I don't see any JavaScript in the jsbin. Provide everything relevant to the question. And it should be working (i.e. fading) in Firefox.

Comment: And here is the source for the initial page load, before clicking anything. http://jsbin.com/ifisuh/2/edit

Comment: Sorry @katspaugh here's everything together: http://jsbin.com/ifisuh/4/edit#preview. Still fails in IE.

Comment: @Jamie, I opened it in both IE7 and IE8 and it fades in and out fine. Is the fading triggered by some event?

Comment: @katspaugh Hmmm, the fading is triggered from the clicking of a link. It looks like I need some more machines to test on as its still not working for me. I've just tried it with no images, just text, and it does fade. I'm baffled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE7/8's opacity support is very flaky. As mentioned in the first comment, it requires ActiveX, so the first port of call is to ensure that:

- your Windows machine supports it (it doesn't like VMs or low-color desktops).
- you have the appropriate DLLs installed.
- your copy of IE has is configured to allow ActiveX in the appropriate zone.

Obviously this would need to be set up correctly for any IE7/8 client. On an intranet, this may mean you have to manually check each user's machine. On the other hand, if your site is going to be used on the internet at large, then you will never have any guarantee that any given IE user will be able to see your opacity effects. (although to be fair, most IE users should be okay)

But even if you can get it to work, IE's opacity has a number of known bugs, especially when working with images. Some of those bugs can be worked around by tweaking the graphic -- using a different image format; avoiding having any pure black or white in the image; don't try to fade images with alpha transparency; etc -- but some bugs simply can't be avoid. You should also avoid trying to fade grpahic and text elements at the same time, as this can make the bugs more noticable (as the text fades more smoothly than the graphic). [I can't find the site I want to reference at the moment which explains some of this in more detail; will edit this answer when (if) I find it]

The bottom line is that fading in IE7/8 is very hit-and-miss. If it goes right for you, great; but very often it simply can't be done in the way you'd want to. For some sites this means that the best solution is simply not to even try fading with IE7/8.

I'm sorry I'm not giving you very good news here. I hope some of the tips I've given will help, but please be prepared in case they don't.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. Of course I was aware IE is tricky hand't realised the variables in play and the subtleties of some bugs. I'll was testing on a VM and I've tried one other windows machine with IE8, however I'll try a couple more when I get home from work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you wrapped your code?

```
$(function() { // to fire when jquery is loaded
  var data = "<%= escape_javascript(render(@illustrations)) %>";
  var div = $('#illustrations');
  div.fadeOut("slow", function() {
    div.html(data);
    div.fadeIn('slow');
  });
});
```

Make sure this code isn't fired before jquery is loaded, else there might pop up an error which drives IE nuts.

Who knows? It could be a ridicilous problem such as you have an array which is ['example',]
IE 7's entire javascript stops working because there's a non defined array for, instance.

Comment: Is it not better to use `$(document).ready({ ... });`, or do they do the same thing?

Comment: And it's not "when jquery is loaded", it's when the DOM-tree is fully rendered.

Comment: I'm new to Rails and I had thought that javascript delivered through an ajax call was executed on receipt, I'm not sure if that's correct or not? Anyway, I've tried as you said with no luck :(.